# If I use built-in/standard iOS controls in my iPad app will they automatically update with an iOS system update?

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm in the design stage of an iPad app. If I use standard UI elements in my design (e.g. a standard iOS button design) and then get the dev's to implement the standard UI elements without any customization, will they update automatically when iOS 7 update comes out?

If not, what do I need to do when the update comes out? What changes need to be made in the app in order to use the new iOS7 styling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer : No

Descriptive answer: No they won't get updated automatically. You have to recompile your apps using XCode 5 to make sure that your app looks as per new UI controls of iOS 7. If you won't compile them then you will not be able to see even a single UI component and other than this you might get some crashes too.

It is always recommended to recompile your App and test it according to new iOS version to make sure that your apps looks according to newer UI and doesn't crashes on new OS because of changed/ deprecated APIs

Answer (score -1):

I just updated my iPhone to iOS 7 and all my apps still use the old UI elements, (such as NavBar, TabBar, etc).  Not sure yet how to update them to use the new ones, (I haven't updated to XCode 5 for example), but the quick answer is: no, your apps still look the same.